# Return MySQL rows within 10% of a given value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a MySQL database that looks like this:

```
   username   rating
1  xxxxxxxx     -1
2  xxxxxxxx      5
3  xxxxxxxx      14
4  xxxxxxxx      23
5  xxxxxxxx      12
```

Now if I had a given value, say 13, how would I go about returning all the rows where the rating is within 10% either way of 13?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `tblName`
WHERE `rating` BETWEEN 13 * 0.9 AND 13 * 1.1
```

That will work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE rating BETWEEN ? * 0.90 AND ? * 1.10
```

Comment: That would return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
low = min(0, 13 * .9)
high = max(25, 13 * 1.10)
```

assuming maximum rating is 25.  From there it's just basic  low < rating < high query logic.